# Running command line command in Jupyter notebook

Tags: shell, jupyter-notebook, command-line, subprocess, ipython

How can I run the following command line command on Jupyter notebook:

```
$STAND_EXE -d WF5-51
```

where `$STAND_EXE` is environment variable containing path to executible (.exe file) and `WF5-51` is a filename.

Thanks.

I tried

```
subprocess.run([STAND_EXE,'-d','WF-51'])
```

but got an error

Comment: In an ipython session In `!python3 -h` displays its help. And if `astr = 'python3'`, then `!$astr -h` does the same.  This short for magic `%sx` or `%system` .

Comment: How did you get on with my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you did something like this in `bash` first to set your environment variable to the path of an executable:

```
export STAND_EXE=/bin/echo
```

Now inside Python:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp

# Pick up the environment variable
exe = os.environ['STAND_EXE']

# Now run it and save its output
res = sp.run([exe,'-d','WF-51'], stdout=sp.PIPE)

# Print result
print(res.stdout)
```

**Result**

```
b'-d WF-51\n'
```